# Отличие указателей на массив типов char и int

Tags: c++, указатели

Почему в выводе char  получаем целый массив значений, а в int только адрес на первое значение, хотя примеры идентичны. Как вывести адрес каждого элемента я нашел,но это не главное. Хочу понять структуру как работает int с указателем и char с указателем.Где именно начинаются различия?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[3]={0,1,2};
    int *parr = arr;
    cout<<parr<<endl;
    char str []={'h','e','l','p'};
    char *p = str;
    cout<<p;
}

0x7ffd0f412958
help
```

Comment: Ссылки в вопросах давать можно только как поясняющий материал, но вопрос должен быть самодостаточен, чтобы при неработающих ссылках все было понятно. Перенесите код в вопрос! Это куда важнее "Всем привет", которые здесь не приветствуются. Сразу к делу :) Вы же читали, как здесь принято задавать вопросы, правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что есть такая вещь, как перегрузка функций. Функция `operator<<` для `ostream&` и `char*` работает, выводя все символы до нулевого, ну, а функция от `ostream&` и `int*` - совсем иначе, просто выводя адрес...